# getting Anonymous User in SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal() using Spring Boot and JWT token based authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am trying to fetch the User Id of a logged in User.
I am using JWT based authentication.

But each time I am getting anonymous user while executing SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
package com.event.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/users/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/user/checkUsernameAvailability", "/api/user/checkEmailAvailability")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/events/**", "/users/**","/blogs/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/events/**","/blogs/**","/upload/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}
```

**BlogController.java**

```
package com.event.controller;

import com.event.model.Blog;
import com.event.model.EventWithFile;
import com.event.service.BlogService;
import com.event.service.ImageService;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

@RestController
public class BlogController {

    @Autowired
    private BlogService blogService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/blogs")
    private String createNewBlog(@RequestParam("event") String model, @RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Blog blog = mapper.readValue(model, Blog.class);
        UserDetails user =(UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        System.out.println(user.getUsername());
        return "Successfull";
    }
    //TODO : Donot return objects return response Entity
    @GetMapping(value = "/blogs")
    private List<Blog> getBlogs(){

        return blogService.getBlogs();
    }

}
```

**JWTAuthenticationFilter.java**

```
package com.event.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;

public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private Optional<String> getJWTStringFormRequest(HttpServletRequest httprequest) {
        String bearerToken = httprequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return Optional.of(bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length()));
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Optional<String> jwtString = getJWTStringFormRequest(request);
        jwtString.ifPresent(string -> {
            Optional<UserDetails> userDetails = userDetailsService
                    .loadUserByUserId(jwtTokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(string));
            userDetails.ifPresent(user -> {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());
                // No idea what the following line does
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            });
        });

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }


}
```

**SpringSecurityUser.java**

```
package com.event.security;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import com.event.model.User;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

public class SpringSecurityUser implements UserDetails{

    private Integer id;

    private User user;

    private String username;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;


    public SpringSecurityUser(Integer id, User user, String username, String password,
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.id = id;
        this.user = user;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {

        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {

        return username;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {

        return true;
    }


    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

**JWTTokenProvider.java**

```
package com.event.security;

import io.jsonwebtoken.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Date;

@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtTokenProvider.class);

    @Value("${jwtConfidentialCode}")
    private String jwtConfidentialCode;

    @Value("${jwtExpirationTimeInMs}")
    private int jwtExpirationTimeInMs;

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {

        SpringSecurityUser user = (SpringSecurityUser) authentication.getPrincipal();

        Date now = new Date();
        Date expiryDate = new Date(now.getTime() + jwtExpirationTimeInMs);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(Integer.toString(user.getId()))
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(expiryDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtConfidentialCode)
                .compact();
    }

    public Integer getUserIdFromJWT(String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(jwtConfidentialCode)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();

        return Integer.parseInt(claims.getSubject());
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtConfidentialCode).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        }catch (MalformedJwtException ex) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            logger.error("Expired JWT token");
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex) {
            logger.error("Unsupported JWT token");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty.");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your request with URL an headers.

Comment: Any update on this thread?

Comment: @BilalELCHAMI didn't find any fix to the above scenario. Tried a different approach instead

Comment: @SunandanBose In my case one of my frontend modules was not sending the jwt token to the backend which resulted the Anonymous User.

Comment: @BilalELCHAMI It worked for you then?

Comment: Yes so basically, since my backend didn't recieve the token from my frontend module, the JWTAuthenticationFilter didn't execute the follwing code
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);


Try to debug the filters' doFilterInternal function and see why you're not setting the contexts' autehntication properly

Answer (score -1):

Please check your request may not have JWT token in headers.

Comment: do you think it helps?

Comment: It can be comment.